# Is there any way to read the battery permissions of xioami(Redmi) for background process?

Tags: android, battery, batterymanager

I implemented one service which takes location of user for every 3 mins but the problem in xiaomi is default app gets battery saver option because of that it's not updating location.Is there any way to find this and enable??[image]

[image]

By default it is battery saver option I want it to be No restrictions

Answer (score 0):

To open list of apps for choosing battery optimization you can use this code sample:

```
private void openPowerSettings(Context context) {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction(Settings.ACTION_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATION_SETTINGS);
    context.startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: I tried this already it doesn't make any difference at all.Still the app has same permission Battery Optimisation(Recommended)